# Microsoft SQL JDBC driver v6.2 returning incorrect SQL type code for DATETIME fields

Tags: java, sql-server, jdbc, sql-server-2005, mssql-jdbc

Normally, [`ResultSetMetaData#getColumnType()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/sql/ResultSetMetaData.html#getColumnType-int-) should return [`93`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/sql/Types.html#TIMESTAMP) for `DATETIME` fields (usually represented as `java.sql.Timestamp`).

This was indeed true for driver versions **4.2.6420.100** and **4.0.4621.201** (as well as [*jTDS*](http://jtds.sourceforge.net/)).

When using newer Microsoft JDBC drivers (**6.0.7728.100**, **6.0.8112.100** and **6.2.1.0** in partucular) with Microsoft SQL Server 2005 (9.0.1399), I observe a different type code is returned: **-151**, which doesn't even map to any type in `java.sql.Types`.

At the same time, `ResultSetMetaData#getColumnClassName(int)` and `ResultSetMetaData#getColumnTypeName(int)` behave correctly (always returning `java.sql.Timestamp` and `datetime`, respectively).

Here's the unit test which fails when run using the above driver and server combinations:

```
package com.example;

import static org.hamcrest.MatcherAssert.assertThat;
import static org.hamcrest.Matchers.is;

import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.ResultSetMetaData;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.sql.Statement;
import java.sql.Types;

import javax.sql.DataSource;

import org.eclipse.jdt.annotation.Nullable;
import org.testng.annotations.AfterMethod;
import org.testng.annotations.BeforeClass;
import org.testng.annotations.BeforeMethod;
import org.testng.annotations.Test;

import com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnectionPoolDataSource;

public final class MsSqlServerTest {
    @Nullable
    private static DataSource dataSource;

    @Nullable
    private Connection conn;

    @BeforeClass
    public static void setUpOnce() {
        dataSource = new SQLServerConnectionPoolDataSource();
        ((SQLServerConnectionPoolDataSource) dataSource).setURL("jdbc:sqlserver://localhost\\SQLEXPRESS:1433;databaseName=...");
    }

    @BeforeMethod
    public void setUp() throws SQLException {
        this.conn = dataSource.getConnection("...", "...");
    }

    @AfterMethod
    public void tearDown() throws SQLException {
        if (this.conn != null) {
            this.conn.close();
        }
        this.conn = null;
    }

    @Test
    public void testDateTimeCode() throws SQLException {
        try (final Statement stmt = this.conn.createStatement()) {
            try {
                stmt.executeUpdate("drop table test");
            } catch (@SuppressWarnings("unused") final SQLException ignored) {
                // ignore
            }
            stmt.executeUpdate("create table test (value datetime)");

            try (final ResultSet rset = stmt.executeQuery("select * from test")) {
                final ResultSetMetaData metaData = rset.getMetaData();
                assertThat(metaData.getColumnClassName(1), is(java.sql.Timestamp.class.getName()));
                assertThat(metaData.getColumnTypeName(1), is("datetime"));
                assertThat(metaData.getColumnType(1), is(Types.TIMESTAMP));
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The above issue doesn't occur with newer Microsoft SQL Server versions (like 2014).

*SQL Server Management Studio 2014* always reports column type correctly (`DATETIME`), regardless of the version of the server it is connected to.

What's wrong with the JDBC driver? Has Microsoft once again broken compatibility with one of its own products?

Comment: May we ask if this potential bug is somehow impeding JDBC from working properly with your actual Java code?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen Will post the minimalistic example shortly.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen Yes, it is actually. Our Java code relies on JDBC metadata.

Comment: Well-written question +1 and it wouldn't surprise me if MS' JDBC driver has a compatability bug.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"Has Microsoft once again broken compatibility with one of its own products?"

Technically, no, because the current versions of the JDBC driver do not support SQL Server 2005. According to the [SQL Server requirements](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/jdbc/system-requirements-for-the-jdbc-driver#sql-server-requirements) for the JDBC driver:

> For Microsoft JDBC Driver 4.2 and 4.1 for SQL Server, support begins with SQL Server 2008. For Microsoft JDBC Driver 4.0 for SQL Server, support beings [sic] with SQL Server 2005.

This was also [discussed on GitHub](https://github.com/Microsoft/mssql-jdbc/issues/208).

Comment: Thank you for your response. Still, wouldn't it be better to detect server version during the initial handshake and fail fast with a meaningful error message, rather than **silently** continuing to work with a server known to have compatibility issues?

Comment: That is really a judgement call that the product team has to make. Your suggestion makes sense if the overriding priority is to avoid having some users trip over compatibility issues like this. However, it also runs the risk of annoying other users to need to use a newer driver (for some reason), cannot immediately upgrade their server (for some other reason), and are willing to accept the risks associated with running an unsupported configuration. In my experience that latter group is quite prevalent, especially when the server upgrades significantly impact their budget.